# Exporting in Sublime Text Processing Bundle and replicating its features in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bundle, sublimetext2, processing

A video and relevant links can be found at http://vimeo.com/45573600 :

1) It is possible to obtain exactly the same behavior, and especially the library-specific autocomplete in Eclipse? I tried proclipsing and all the instructions for working with processing on Eclipse found on the Processing forum but none of them let's you have that, even if Aptana Studio 3, which is based on Eclipse, does the same for HTML & CSS.

2) After I installed the bundle in Sublime Text 2, I noticed that, even if I can find in the documentation that "With cmd+shift+b and typing build you get alternative buildsystems: Run sketch fullscreen and various Export sketch options" this doesn't work at all for me. Maybe is just because I am on a PC and I had to try CTRL+shift+b, but anyway there is no trace of it even in the menus. Any hint?

Comment: ask the guys that made the sublime text 2 plugin?

Comment: I did of course and, while for the second problem some help was offered, the first problem has been in fact the reason why the developer made the bundle. I would like to learn to work in Eclipse even just for this beginner language since I know it is a much more widespread and valued work environment.

Comment: One guaranteed way to make eclipse understand the Processing API is to include it as a .jar library dependency to your project, and then for completeness attaching the source code to it as well. This will let Eclipse do the normal Java thing, which in 99% of the cases is enough for using Processing (which is based on the Java syntax). The problem with that, however, is that you're no longer writing Processing, but Java with Processing as a library... I personally just use Sublime for my Processing projects, the API is small enough to look up online in my experience.